# Problem pushing to GitHub with Codenvy: "Can't store ssh key. Unable get private ssh key."

Tags: git, github, oauth, ide, cloud

I am using Codenvy for my rails app. When I run `git push -u origin --all` with my rails application i get a blank terminal. When I push using the `Git > Remotes > Push menu`, I get the error "`Can't store ssh key. Unable get private ssh key."`

Is this a problem with OAuth, because I have not set that up yet. I tried following the Codenvy git documentation, but they provided no info on what to fill into the `<HOST_IP>`, `<SERVER_PORT>`, `<CHE_HOST_IP>`, `yourClientSecret`, and `yourClientID` parameters. I have followed many online tutorials trying to connect my Codenvy App to GitHub, and none of them have been successful. I cannot seem to find one definitive way to do this. I am new to Codenvy, so could you please explain this to me?

**Reproduction Steps:**
I have already:

- Added my Git user info to my preferences
- Added my GitHub info using `git config --global user.name/email "name/email"`
- Added my remote origin with my repository name using `git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:/`
- Generated an SSH key using VCS under the host name "github.com" and added the public ssh to my GitHub account

**UPDATE:** I have fixed by git origin and now when I run `git push -u origin -all`, I get the following error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Git-Ibraheem/toy_app.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

When using the Codenvy Git menu, I get the same error:

```
failed to push 'master -> master' to 'https://github.com/Git-Ibraheem/toy_app.git'. Try to merge remote changes using pull, and then push again.
```

When I run `git pull origin master` I get the following:

```
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.`
```

**Fix:**
I ran the command `git reset --hard HEAD` and then `git push -u origin --all`. This was succesful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:/

That should be a full URL `git@bitbucket.org:/MyAccount/MyRepo`

> Generated an SSH key using VCS under the host name "github.com" and added the public ssh to my GitHub account

That... would have nothing to do with `bitbucket` then (which you just mentioned as your "origin").

> Is this a problem with OAuth,

If you are using SSH, OAuth is not involved, so no.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks!